# Partially isolated scope angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I have a **directive** that i want to include **multiple** times on a page.
I also want to control this directive from the **parent controller**.

To give an example, the directive is a modal has a **transcluded** partial in it. This partial has a form that sends a message.

I want to dictate what that form does from my **parent controller** however when i isolate the scope (so that i can have more than one of these directives per page) i can no longer access the form object that angular creates.

im open to suggestions

### html page

```
<page controller="pageCtrl">
  <modal partial="/path/to/partial1"></modal>
  <modal partial="/path/to/partial2"></modal>
</page>
```

### html partial 1&2

```
partial1.html
  <form name="formName1"></form>
partial2.html
  <form name="formName1"></form>
```

### JS

```
app.directive('modal', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope:true,
    templateUrl: '/path/to/modal.html',
    link:function($scope, elem, attrs){
      $http.get(attrs.partial, { cache: $templateCache })
      .success(function(response) {
        element.find('[ng-transclude]').append(response);
        $compile(element.find('[ng-transclude]').contents())($scope);
      });
    }
  }
});
app.controler('pageCtrl', function(){
  $scope.submitForm1 = function(data){
    if($scope.formName1.$valid){
      //DO SOMETHING
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after typing it all out i realized how to do such a thing.
My goal was to isolate the scope of the directive but not the scope of the form inside.
So all i had to do was change what scope my included form/modal content was compiling against;

`$compile(element.find('[ng-transclude]').contents())($scope.$parent);`
Instead of;
`$compile(element.find('[ng-transclude]').contents())($scope);`

Thanks anyway

-James Harrington